# Non convex uniform grid triangulation

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I'm trying to triangulate a non convex uniform point grid in 2D. I would need triangles only in the 8-neighborhood of each point. The problem is that when using vtkDelaunay2D I obtain triangles that violate this condition, resulting (in some configurations) in convex planar figures triangulations even if there exists a non convex triangulation.

[image: The delaunay triangulation usually generates more triangles than necessary in this case, turning a non convex figure into a convex figure in many situations.]

I can implement this kind of triangulation, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel. Which algorithm could I use to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boundary of the Delaunay triangulation is necessarily the convex hull of the point set. But if your points are on a regular grid, and you only want to admit triangles spanning one grid step only, why bother with Delaunay at all? Just traverse your grid two rows at a time, and triangulate wherever you can.